# SlidingMenu which resizes main layout instead of overlapping or shifting it

Tags: android, slidingmenu

Is there any way to have sliding menu which resizes main layout to fill available space instead of overlapping or resizing it?

Actually I don't need a menu, I need a component with described behavior. It will be expanded by button click so no touch handling is needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the following site for sliding menu:

http://www.fantageek.com/562/make-your-own-sliding-menu-on-android-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Inside your activity in manifestXML add this attribut

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
  </activity>
```